# problema de scope en python

Tags: python, scope, fibonacci

parece que tengo un problema de scope en python, pero el programa funciona bien, salvo que al final de la ejecucion me aparece el error.

cuando elegimos la 2 opcion me aparece este problema:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 42, in 
while inicio <= final:
NameError: name 'inicio' is not defined

me dice que no esta definido, pero no encuentro forma de quitar ese error sin que me provoque otro error y funcione de la misma manera que ha estado funcionado, porque necesito que el usuario inserte los numeros. si lo saco los input del while, entonces siempre se imprimen los input aunque la opcion sea automatica, lo cual no es lo que quiero, alguien sabe como arreglar ese error?

````
#automatica    
num1 = 0
num2 = 1
while opcion==2:
   print("ha elegido la opcion automatica, el programa empiezara un conteo desde el cero hasta el 100. ¡OJO! /0o0\, termina en 89 ya que la suma de los 2 ultimos numero supera al numero 100. \n")
   break

while opcion==2 and num1 <= 100:
    print(num1)
    (num1,num2) = (num2,num1+num2)  

#manual
b = 0

while opcion==1:
    print("ha elegido la opcion manual,usted decidira el numero con el que inicia y finaliza el programa, luego el programa hara un conteo sumando los dos ultimos numeros y asi sucesivamente. Ahora llene las siguientes casillas:\n")
    inicio = int(input("coloque aqui el numero inicial:"))
    final=int(input("coloque aqui el numero final:"))
    break
    
while inicio <= final:
       print(inicio)
       (inicio,b) = (b,inicio+b)
       continue

    
print("\nFin\n")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios `while` innecesarios, además no se tiene sentido usar `break` o `continue` sin un bloque condicional (`if`).

El error pasa porque el script se recorre de arriba a abajo, y cuando se topa con la línea: `while opcion==2:` da un mensaje de que no has definido una variable que se llame `opcion`.

Si `opcion` es **1** entonces cuando llega al último `while`, `while inicio <= final:`, ni `inicio` ni `final` están definidos (porque se definen en la opcion 2) y por eso te salta el error que pusiste.

Arreglando un poco el código, quedaría así:

```
print("1- Manual")
print("2- Auto (0 - 100)")
opcion = int(input("Seleccione una opcion: "))

if opcion == 1:
    print("Ha elegido la opcion manual, usted decidira el numero con el que inicia y finaliza el programa.")
    print("Luego el programa hara un conteo sumando los dos ultimos numeros y asi sucesivamente.")
    print("Ahora llene las siguientes casillas:\n")
    inicio = int(input("coloque aqui el numero inicial: "))
    final = int(input("coloque aqui el numero final: "))
elif opcion == 2:
    print("ha elegido la opcion automatica, el programa empiezara un conteo desde el cero hasta el 100.") 
    print("¡OJO! /0o0\, termina en 89 ya que la suma de los 2 ultimos numero supera al numero 100. \n")
    inicio = 0
    final = 100
else:
    final = -1 # Con esto no entrará al while más abajo y terminará el programa

num1 = 0
num2 = 1
while num1 <= final:
    if num1 >= inicio: # [ Opcion 1]: omitirá los numeros menores al inicio
        print(num1)
    (num1, num2) = (num2, num1+num2)

print("\nFin\n")
```